# The Convert button is not available in "Salesforce Mobile & Lightning Actions"

Tags: lightning-action

The Convert button is not available in "Salesforce Mobile & Lightning Actions" in order for me to make the button visible in Lightning for myself (system admin) or my users. How can I make that available to add to the section?

[image]

Comment: Your Image is not clear? Can you put a good enough to zoom it and see what is there?

Comment: I re-did the picture; is that better? What I'm showing you is that "Convert" is not an available option for Salesforce Mobile & Lightning Actions so I can't make the button visible in Lightning. I need this button to be available in Lightning.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer and wanted to share. My "Convert" button is overridden to a VF page and there if you open that VF page, there is a checkbox that needs to be checked for that VF to be visible in Lightning. Once this box is checked, the "Convert" button is available to be used in the Salesforce Mobile & Lightning Actions section, thus, visible on the Lead layout.

[image: VF Page]

Comment: Thank you! This was baffling me